# test report showing successful tests but jacoco report showing 0 coverage

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

I have multi project in gradle (java). We have service-core and multiple platform dependent code. When I run build for platform eg. aws then service-core and aws gets compiled.
service-core and aws both has unit tests and both are running (generating file build/reports/tests/test/index.html in aws & service-core)

But jacoco report (build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html) for service core has coverage but for aws does not.

Using java 11 and gradle 7.4

```
buildscript {
    //apply from: "gradle/repositories.gradle"
    apply from: 'versions.gradle'
    //TODO: need to merge versions.gradle with repositories.gradle
    apply from:'repositories.gradle'
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.3'
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-pdf:1.5.0-alpha.10.1'
        classpath 'io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'
        classpath 'io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-spring-restdocs-ext:1.3.3'
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.14.RELEASE"
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.4"
        classpath "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:5.3.2.1"
        classpath 'se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.4'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.8'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.3'
}

apply plugin: 'io.github.swagger2markup'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

//by us
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: 'project-report'
apply plugin: 'org.owasp.dependencycheck'

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


sourceCompatibility = 1.11
targetCompatibility = 1.11



version = "${version != 'unspecified' ? version : '0.0.0'}"
group = 'com.demo'



sonarqube {
    properties {
        properties["sonar.analysis.mode"] = "publish"
        properties["sonar.projectKey"] = System.getenv("SONAR_PROJECT_KEY").toString().trim()
        properties["sonar.projectName"] = System.getenv("SONAR_PROJECT_NAME").toString().trim()
        properties["sonar.host.url"] = System.getenv("SONAR_HOST").toString().trim()
        properties["sonar.login"] = System.getenv("SONAR_TOKEN").toString().trim()


        
        properties["sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths"] = ["$projectDir/platform/aws/build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"]


        //properties["sonar.branch.name"] = "master"
        properties["sonar.branch.name"] = System.getenv("CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME").toString().trim()

    }
}

// IDE configuration
subprojects { final Project subproject ->
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    eclipse {
        project {
            name = rootProject.name + '-' + subproject.name
        }
    }
    idea {
        module {
            name = rootProject.name + '-' + subproject.name
        }
    }
}


project.ext.noDefaultPublication = true

subprojects { final Project subproject ->
    if (!subproject.subprojects.empty) return

    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    version = rootProject.version
    group = rootProject.group


    bootJar.enabled = false
    bootRun.enabled = false
    jar.enabled = true


    ext {
        asciiDocOutputDir = file("${projectDir}/docs")
        snippetsOutputDir = file("${buildDir}/asciidoc/snippets")
        snippetsDir = file("${buildDir}/generated-snippets")
    }

    sourceSets {
        integration {
            java {
                compileClasspath += main.output
                compileClasspath += main.compileClasspath

                compileClasspath += test.output
                compileClasspath += test.compileClasspath
                runtimeClasspath += test.runtimeClasspath

            }
        }
        featureTests {
            java {
                compileClasspath += main.output
                compileClasspath += main.compileClasspath

                compileClasspath += test.output
                compileClasspath += test.compileClasspath
                runtimeClasspath += test.runtimeClasspath
            }
        }
    }
    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            //mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Edgware.SR6'
            mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.4'
            mavenBom 'org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.3.23'
        }
    }



    ext['spring-security.version'] = '5.2.4.RELEASE'

    dependencies {
       // dependencies
    }

    task pathingJar(type: Jar) {
        dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
        archiveAppendix = 'pathing'

        doFirst {
            manifest {
                attributes "Class-Path": configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect {
                    it.toURI().toURL().toString().replaceFirst('/file:/+/', '/')
                }.join(' ')
            }
        }
    }

    bootRun {
        dependsOn pathingJar
        doFirst {
            classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", pathingJar.archivePath)
        }
    }


    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.8.8"
    }



    jacocoTestReport {
        getAdditionalSourceDirs().setFrom(files(project(":service-core").sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs))
        getSourceDirectories().setFrom(files(project(":service-core").sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs))
        getClassDirectories().setFrom(files(project(":service-core").sourceSets.main.output))
        getExecutionData().setFrom(files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"))
        reports {
            xml.required = true
        }
    }


    test {
        outputs.dir snippetsDir

        afterTest { desc, result ->
            logger.quiet "Executing test ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
        }

        finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    }


    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core') {
                    if (details.requested.name != 'jackson-databind') {
                        details.useVersion "${jacksonDatabind}"
                    }
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.logging.log4j') {
                    details.useVersion "${log4j}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

tasks.sonarqube.dependsOn 'platform:aws:build'
```